# Servlet Faces - Erro in context with path

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces, template

Bom dia,

Como já havia dito em outro tópico não é minha área web mais estou tentando kkkk...
Após adicionar um template responsive com nome de Prologue estou com o seguinte erro.

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/ibmo] threw exception [javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config] with root cause
```

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config

**pom.xml**

```
<!-- Repositórios -->
```

```
    <!-- PRIMEFACES -->
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>  
        <version>5.3</version>  
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSF API -->
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
         <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.1.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSF IMPL -->
    <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SERVLET API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Implementação do JSF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicione no seu pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

E veja se funciona, esse erro `ClassNotFoundException` geralmente ocorre quando alguma biblioteca está ausente de seu projeto

Comment: Bom, resolveu. Só que agora está dizendo na execução da página:"HTTP Status 404 - /ibmo/index.jsp" minha página é html...

Comment: você tem a pagina index.jsp no projeto?

Comment: Pior que não. Como disse estou usando template do prologue ele é "index.html"

Comment: Então você já começou errado rs, pelo que vi você quer usar JSF. Se for mesmo usar JSF esses templates não irão funcionar.

Comment: Agora, se você quiser podes usar JSP, Spring, Struts. Mas pra isso você precisará fazer outras configurações.

Comment: Ah, tá. Muito obrigado ! Vou vê o que eu faço. Abraço!